# How to turn off sliding sign-in screen windows Server 2012

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2012

I frequently work from a long distance over VPN with a not-great internet connection. I use Remote Desktop to log onto the Windows Server 2012.

Every time I want to log in I wait for the log in window to appear. After it appears, the big user icons slowly slide to the left before settling in one spot. It takes about 10 seconds with the remote window updating multiple times before I can finally click the user button to log in. Then to double the pain the password screen does the exact same thing. Sliding, updating agonizingly slowly.

What can be done to speed the process? How do I turn off the sliding behavior?

Comment: Maybe this might help: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/disable-visual-effects-windows ?

Comment: @cdavid Thanks a lot for the link. It didn't change the log in sliding animation but a lot of the other optimizations are great. Much obliged.

Comment: @cdavid I actually found a workaround. I realized I could save the login credentials with the RDP file and it no longer asks for a login after connecting.

Comment: That works as well :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround that might work for some people.

Just click the check box to Allow Saving Credentials. Then connect and in the password box, click to save the login credentials. It will no longer ask for a log-in after connecting.